# WordPress - how to retrieve the input type="file"?

Tags: wordpress

I've made a `<form>` with `<input file="file">` into **Wordpress** and I want to retrieve this file to use it. `$_POST['file'];` is only giving me the file name.
I'm OK with saving theses files into the media library of Wordpress.

Any idea how I should proceed ?

Thanks!

Comment: In php, you have to access `$_FILES` to access file type, you can't get filename into `$_POST`. Read http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

// Check that the nonce is valid, and the user can edit this post.
if ( 
    isset( $_POST['my_image_upload_nonce'], $_POST['post_id'] ) 
    && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['my_image_upload_nonce'], 'my_image_upload' )
    && current_user_can( 'edit_post', $_POST['post_id'] )
) {
    // The nonce was valid and the user has the capabilities, it is safe to continue.

    // These files need to be included as dependencies when on the front end.
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );

    // Let WordPress handle the upload.
    // Remember, 'my_image_upload' is the name of our file input in our form above.
    $attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'my_image_upload', $_POST['post_id'] );

    if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
        // There was an error uploading the image.
    } else {
        // The image was uploaded successfully!
    }

} else {

    // The security check failed, maybe show the user an error.
}
```

Source:

```
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload
```

Answer (score 0):

**php file that save file or image**

```
if(isset($_FILES)){ 
        foreach( $_FILES as $file ) 
        {
            if( is_array( $file ) ) {
                $attachment_id = upload_user_file( $file );                //Call function 
                //add your code to use attachment id
            }
        }  
}
```

**In function.php** of your current activated theme

```
function upload_user_file( $file = array() ) {    
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php' );
    $file_return = wp_handle_upload( $file, array('test_form' => false ) );
    if( isset( $file_return['error'] ) || isset( $file_return['upload_error_handler'] ) ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $filename = $file_return['file'];
        $attachment = array(
            'post_mime_type' => $file_return['type'],
            'post_title' => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'inherit',
            'guid' => $file_return['url']
        );
        $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file_return['url'] );
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
        $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $filename );
        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $attachment_data );
        if( 0 < intval( $attachment_id ) ) {
          return $attachment_id;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```